# Changing ASP.NET MVC 3 controller routing behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

Let's say I have a few controllers with long names like VeryLongNameController.

By default ASP.NET MVC3 will map ~/VeryLongName or ~/verylongname to this controller. However I don't like the use of capital names within the URL and would like it to map all long named controllers like ~/very-long-name instead.

I know that it's possible to add custom routes one by one, but is there a way to change the default behavior?

Comment: out of curiosity, what scenarios would a URI be off like this that you would change it for?

Comment: It's just mainly for cosmetics, where I want the URIs to not contain capital letters and also be more readable . i.e. /a-controller-with-long-name instead of /AControllerWithLongName. I was curious if it was possible at all.

Comment: I added an answer below - unfortunately this only applies to the action name - if that helps at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've investigated this a bit more, and got it working by making my own IHttpHandler and IRouteHandler, looking at the source for [System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/66799#266503) and [System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/66799#266505) and basically copying and pasting and replacing how it resolves the controller name. However I don't like this approach at all, as it feels too heavy-weight to redo the whole request processing pipe for a simple cosmetic task. Thus, I will go with adding manual routes for each controller which has two names (which there aren't that many).

UPDATE: I've come with a much simpler solution, and that is done through overriding ControllerFactory .

```
public class ControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    public override IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, 
        string controllerName)
    {
        requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] =
            requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString().Replace("-", "");
        return base.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName.Replace("-",""));
    }
}
```

My blog post about it: http://cangencer.wordpress.com/2011/05/27/better-looking-urls-in-asp-net-mvc-3/

Answer (score 4):

You can, you need to provide your own route handler implementing `IRouterHandler`, there's a good example [here](http://codingcockerel.co.uk/2008/05/26/custom-routing-for-asp-net-mvc/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ActionName attribute specifically for an action method.. not a controller though

```
[ActionName("an-action-with-long-name")]
public ActionResult AnActionWithLongName() {
  // ...
}
```

Also - I prefer to add a route for *every* controller/action method so I don't create any unexpected mappings (I unit test them as well too) - so this is one thing to consider.

Comment: actually this is exactly what I want to avoid, not to have to define it individually for each controller or action. :)